# Laravel Ajax jquery get values on click tr rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an html table that contains product information:

1. id
2. Title

And when I click on a row or several rows I would like to retrieve the ids in array and modify their title through the controller.

Example :

I click on the first row I get the first id and when I click on the second row I get the second id but the first id it disappears.

I try with this :

**Ajax**

```
 var last_clicked;

$(document).on('click', "#Mytable tr:not(:first)", function () {


       $('#id_product').val(last_clicked.find('[class="fill_id_product"]').html());

 });

$('#update_product').click(function() { 
    var id = $('#id_product').val();
    var array_id = array.push(id);
    alert(array_id) ;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{action('ProdcutController@updateProduct')}}",
        data: {
            id: array_id,
        },

    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
    }                               
    });                             

 });
```

**HTMl :**

```
 <a  id="update_product">Update Prodcut</a>

//Table
<table id="Mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-checkable order-column">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id </th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($all_products as $all_product)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="fill_id_product">{{$all_product->id}}</p> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p hidden class="fill_title">{{$all_product->title}}</p> 
                </td>  
            </tr>
        @endforeach
            <input type="text" name="" id="id_product">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**And My controler :**

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request){
        $products = Product::where('id',$request->id)->get();
        foreach($products as $product){
        $product->title = "Title global";
        $product->save();
        }
        return ['products' => $products];
}
```

Comment: share rendered html and java-script which can be seen as live mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to push the id into array on row click function.

Here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <a  id="update_product">Update Prodcut</a>
    <table id="Mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-checkable order-column">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id </th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="fill_id_product">1</p> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p hidden class="fill_title">Title 1</p> 
                    </td>  
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="fill_id_product">2</p> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p hidden class="fill_title">Title 2</p> 
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="fill_id_product">3</p> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p hidden class="fill_title">Title 3</p> 
                    </td>  
                </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script>
    var clicked_ids = [];
    $(document).on('click', "#Mytable tr:not(:first)", function () {
    var product_id = $(this).find('[class="fill_id_product"]').html();
    alert(product_id);
    if(clicked_ids.indexOf(product_id) == -1){  
    clicked_ids.push(product_id);
    }

     console.log(clicked_ids);
     });


    $('#update_product').click(function() { 
        console.log(clicked_ids);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{action('ProdcutController@updateProduct')}}",
            data: {
                id: clicked_ids,
            },

        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
        }                               
        });                             

     });
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Also you need to change the controller login because you are now sending the ids in array no a single id so you need to change condition to `where id IN($request->id)`

Comment: Hi Wassem 
Thank's. 
when I click on the first row and the second, the array contains example (1,2) It works very well .
But when I click once again on the first row I would like to remove the 1 in the array.

Comment: Please use the else block for this if id is already in array then remove this.
else{  var index = clicked_ids.indexOf(product_id);
          clicked_ids.splice(index, 1);
  }